# Keyboard problem in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

I have listview ,below that there is one edittext with the  button in the right side .when ever i typed some content in the edittext ,soft keyboard popsup so my edittext moves up but listview not.I want my listview also moves up,so that last message updated in the listview can be visible even the soft keyboard pops up.how to solve this?

Comment: Could you post XML layout code.

Answer (score 0):

add this in menifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".activity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```